# Unable to connect to Microsoft SSRS 2012 via SSMS or Report Server/Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssms, reportserver

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server Developer Edition in my local machine for my own development use with a Windows Authentication. I have been able to connect to DB Engine, SSAS (Multidimensional Model) Engine, SSIS Engine, SSAS (Tabular Model Engine using another instance).

I was able to connect to SSRS engine (Native Mode) a few weeks earlier. Recently I installed CheckPoint SSL VPN to access our client Remote Desktop. After this installation, whenever I connect to SSRS either using SSMS or Report Server or Report Manager, even though the SSRS Services is running (I have been able to verify from SQL Server Configuration Manager as well as Reporting Services Configuration Manager). I even tried to add the SSRS Report Server link in the SSMS for the SSRS Engine, but still not successful.

I get the following:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to LAPTOPNAME\SQL2012DEV.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Unable to connect to the server at LAPTOPNAME\SQL2012DEV. The specified URL might not be valid or there might be a problem with the report server version or configuration. Specify a different URL, or contact your 
server administrator to verify that the report server runs SQL Server 2008 or later. Additionally, if you are trying to connect to a SharePoint-integrated report server, verify that SharePoint is installed on the server
 and that the report server uses SharePoint integrated mode. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)

---

BUTTONS:

OK

Could this be due to some permission issues ? I have restarted the SSRS services many times, though it is running, I am not able to connect. Should some Admin privileges be given to my Windows account ? If so, can you guide me how ?

Information from SQL Server Configuration Manager (for SSRS service):
Log on As: NT Service\ReportServer$SQL2012DEV

Information from Reporting Serivces Configuration Manager:
Service Account is built-in:  ReportServer$SQL2012DEV

Should I change built-in account to Local Service, Network Service, Local System ?

Answer (score 0):

Open "Reporting Services Configuration Manager" in "Web Service URL" OR "Web Portal URL" tab check your IP and Port access & use the link in URLs to be sure. I think your new application changed this settings.

Comment: The new application has not changed these settings. The URL of Report Server or Report Manager has not changed. The TCP Port used is 80